# Call another directive from the directive with the same attributes and content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I want to override behaviour of one library directive, called **"ui-sref"**. Lets see example:

```
<a ui-sref="edit" class="btn btn-small">
     <i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit
 </a>
```

Now, I want to create my own directive called, for example, **"ui-sref-appended"**. Code will be like this:

```
<a ui-sref-appended="edit" class="btn btn-small">
     <i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit
 </a>
```

The output I want must be:

```
<a ui-sref="user.edit" class="btn btn-small">
     <i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit
 </a>
```

(and then complied, so *ui-sref* could done his job)

How can I implement this? The problem is that i want my **a** to have the same attributes and content, but changed from **ui-sref-appended="edit"** to **ui-sref="user.edit"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set template of your new directive as follows

```
 template : '<a ui-sref="user.edit" class="btn btn-small"> <i class="icon-pencil"</i> Edit</a>';
```

And set the user.edit in the link function or pass the user to directive via scope member.

If you have dynamic template, you can create the directive template in link function.

```
 app.directive('newDirective', function ($compile) {
        return {

            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var template= '<a ui-sref="user.edit" class="{{btnClass}}"> <i class="icon-pencil"</i> Edit </a>';
element.append($compile(template)(scope));
            },
            scope: {
                user: '=',
                btnClass: '@'
            }
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**

If you want to just set the ui-sref, simply add the ui-sref as an attribute to your element and then compile it.

```
 app.directive('uiSrefAppended', function ($compile) {
        return { 
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.attr('ui-sref', 'user.edit');
                $compile(element)(scope);
            },
            scope: {
                user: '='
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: content and attributes are dynamic - can be whatever, i cannot set it as a template

Comment: Do you have the parameter in link function?

Comment: I Edit my post . so you can change the template in link function.

Comment: `template` variable in your code is HARDCODED, it cant be hardcoded, because it can be ANYTHING, for example *<button ui-sref="......*

Comment: ui-sref="user.edit", user is a variable that passed to the directive. Even the css class can be passed to the directive. Look at my edited post.

Comment: look, directive can be appended to ANY tag (not only *a*) with ANY attributes (not only *class*), but your code can work only with both of them, but I need to work with ANY